# Django application global variables in database best praxis

Tags: django, django-models, orm, django-settings, django-apps

I am a new in django. I storage global application variables inside settings environment folder. But now i need store variables inside Database because  i want changes them from django admin.
My way to do this: Create model class in django core, where define two variable app_name  - list of application and data-JSON. But i think this is not best praxis. Since it may be difficult to use the GIT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to use a ready-made solution: [django-extra-setting](https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/django-extra-settings).
In apps setting define variables that will be storage in DB:

```
DB_VARIABLES = {'variable_name': ['text', 'default_value']}
```

Reads a variable from files after django project has been loaded

```
from settings import PROJECT_APPS
from extra_settings.models import Setting
from importlib import import_module
class CoreConfig(AppConfig):
    def ready(self):
        if (is_manage_py and is_runserver) or (not is_manage_py):
              local_settings = import_module(f'path/{app_name}')
        for app_name in PROJECT_APPS:
            local_constants = local_settings.DB_VARIABLES if hasattr(local_settings, 'DB_VARIABLES') else False
            if local_constants:
                variables = {**variables, **{key: local_constants[key] for key in local_constants}}
                for constant_name in local_constants:
                    if Setting.objects.filter(name=constant_name).count() == 0:
                        constant_values = local_constants[constant_name]
                        Setting(name=constant_name, value_type=constant_values[0], value=constant_values[1]).save()
```